# Prevent creation of empty files in bash

Tags: bash, grep

I wrote the following code, where:

- `$1` = Input .csv file
- `$2` = list of strings to be searched in `$1`
- `$3` = list of different strings to be searched in `$2`

```
while read str1
do
    while read str2
    do
     grep $str1 $1 | grep $str2 | cut -d "," -f 6 > ${str1}_${str2}.txt
    done < $3
done < $2
```

It basically does what I want it to do (search for two different strings from separate input files, extract field 6 of lines that contain both strings and write the content of field 6 into a result file).
However, of course, result files are created for all possible combinations of strings from $2 and $3, even if they are empty. Is there a way to prevent the creation of empty files in general or do I have to remove them at the end?

Comment: An improvement in many ways would be to rewrite this as an Awk script which processes each input file just once. Then writing only files for which you have a result is easily and naturally expressed.

Comment: As an aside, you need quotes basically everywhere. Try http://shellcheck.net/ for detailed diagnostics.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if given details of the input formats (ie. if the items being matched from a given input are all in a single column) much of the work we're currently calling two `grep`s per line over could be modified to a single-pass `join` piped to a loop (in `awk`, if we cared about performance) that splits results out into separate files. But details matter, and they aren't adequately given here.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture program output with $(...):

```
res=$(grep "$str1" "$1" | grep "$str2" | cut -d "," -f 6)
```

and with -n test, if a String is empty:

```
if [[ -n $res ]]; then echo "$res" > "${str1}_${str2}.txt" ; fi
```